# Move jQuery event handlers from main window to popup

Tags: html, jquery

I am having problems with event jQuery events on a popup window.

In my main window I have a div acting as a window/dialog that has varying content. I have a button to 'pop out' the 'window' into a popout, allowing users with multiple screens to use my app across them.

How it works, is when the button is pressed, a popup opens with the destination of 'popout.html', onload 'popout.html' calls a function to grab the contents of the div from the main page and place it into the popout. so the content dissapears from the main window and appears in the popup.

That is all working fine, Except any event handler I attach with jQuery like `$('<button>Do Something</button>').on('click', console.log).appendTo(newBoxContent);` still gets executed on the main window, not the popup. How do I move all these events?

Comment: In this case you might need to write all the jQuery code in a .js file and reload it once again in the popout window

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth Unfortunately I can't really do that, as the event handlers are added to elements on creation as needed. I am thinking i may have to attach an object as follows to each element on creation: `{function: console.log, event: 'click'}` as something like `data-functionHelper`. then in the popup `$('[data-functionHelper]').each(...)` and `.off` and `.on` them again.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is very simple or even possible to "transfer".

You can include the script that set up the event handlers in the parent document in the new window. This is needed because a new window will not inherit handlers

Alternatively pass in the scope in the function that sets the event handlers

```
function setHandlers(scope) {
  $('element.class',scope).on('click', console.log);
}

$(function() {
  sethandlers(window)
  $("#pop").on("click",function() {
   const w = window.open("popup.html");
   if (w) setHandlers(w)
 })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that wont work, as I am generally applying the event handlers when creating the elements (edited question to better reflect this)

I am thinking I may have to attach an object containg the type of event, the function its calling and any other assosiated info to the element on creation, then when I run the popOut function, have it loop through all elements and `.off()` and `.on()` them again in the new scope (jquery is set up in popout.html as well)

Comment: Then you will need to rethink the way you do it OR copy the scripts that create/assign the handlers into the new window

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small sample to copy the entire content of a page including scripts. You can strip the script code, then may be append it in the new page load and then reattach events.

```js
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $('body').append($('<div />').text($('form').html()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Click Me</a>
<form>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />

<script>
$("input").on("click",function(){alert("x");});
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: That is not a good solution as that will require me to litter my html with <script> tags. at that point i may as well just do `<button onclick="console.log(event);">Do Something</button>`